# How can I display column names in the result of queries?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to display the name of columns on the top of my file instead of getting only the data I wanna also get the name of the columns
I'm using ORACLE 12C
[image: EXAMPLE]

Comment: The answer depends on what tool you're using to create the file. If you're using SQL\*Plus, then Littlefoot's answer should work. Can you edit the question and add some more context?

Comment: @JonHeller Thank you for your answer
I don't use any tool I'm trying to consult my database from an ERP (an application I work with)
my goal is to extract data from my database in a flat-file but unfortunately, I cannot display the names of the extracted columns

Answer (score 0):

What you described sounds as if you turned headings off in SQL*Plus. Something like this: by default, headings are visible:

```
SQL> select * from dept where deptno = 10;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
```

If you turn them off:

```
SQL> set heading off
SQL>
SQL> select * from dept where deptno = 10;

        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply 
I'm trying to extract data from my database in a flat file but unfortunately, I cannot display the names of the extracted columns at the top of my flat file

Comment: If it is ERP (you mentioned in another comment), then you'll have to talk to people who developed it.

Answer (score 0):

While display logic should usually be handled in the application, there are workarounds to accomplish something similar with SQL. The below statement uses a few tricks to create an initial row of column names:

```
select name, age, nationality, city
from
(
    select 1 header_1_data_2, 'Name' name, 'Age' age, 'Nationality' nationality, 'City' city
    from dual
    union all
    select 2 header_1_data_2, name, to_char(age), nationality, city
    from student
)
order by header_1_data_2;
```